# Amout of Memory assigned to a Process Operating System

Tags: operating-system

Is there a fixed amount of memory allowed for a process as a barrier.
because after generating a lot of objects in the heap ~ 3*10^8 JVM consumes about 1.162.4 GB of ram and after that it gives OutOfMemoryError. why can't i generate objects till the end of the capacity of the heap?
or is this related to the JVM or the operating system is doing this?

```
class c  {
    public static void main(String str[]){
        int a[] = new int[300000000];

        while(true){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)

Comment: no its not please don't spoil the question ... i did't got the exact answer...
as i said i my system i am able to use 1.2 GB for allocation instead of 2GB as stated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error

Comment: Can you check your numbers?  3*10^9 represented in 1.2GB is about 0.42 bytes per object.  That seems a little low.

Comment: A bit more reasonable, 4.2 bytes per object; but given that somewhere there has to be a pointer to the object (4 bytes), and some garbage collection info, I find this still a bit too small.   Where are you storing your object references?   If you aren't assigning them to a list, map, ...,  https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded might be your issue.

Comment: @mevets edited again.. and data it 100% accurate .. hope this helps..

Comment: I am over my head.  I tried your program; it seem to consistently oom @ 250 000 000, which corresponds to 1G of memory just for the object.

Comment: are you able to conclude anything now ??